# UIImagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

Hope you're all doing well. Wondered if anyone could help me understand why Xcode fails to play nice with me....

I have broken the code into sections below in order to allow me to select a profile photo from UIImagePicker:

1. WORKS: Assigning the delegate class for both ImagePicker & NavigationController
2. WORKS: Instantiating the UIImagePicker variable
3. WORKS: Load ImagePickerViewController and enable to select an image
4. FAILS: Added additional functions for closing and finishing picking with a UIImagePicker but neither ever get called? What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance!

---

```
class ProfileVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
```

---

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
}
```

---

```
@IBAction func selectPhotoPressed(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.PhotoLibrary) {
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    } else {
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
    }
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    headerView.profilePhoto.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    headerView.profilePhoto.image = image
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    uploadImage(image)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

OK I seem to have it working now, thanks for your help in identifying that the code was ancient ;) Here is what now runs:

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    headerView.profilePhoto.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    headerView.profilePhoto.image = image
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    uploadImage(image!)
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it working. I will update my answer too because I noticed I got the signature slightly wrong too (it's correct in yours).

Comment: Worth noting `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` will, as it says, get you the original image, not including any edits or modifications the user may have done. For that you'd use `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`.

Answer (score 2):

You have the signature wrong, but since it's an optional method, you are not getting warned. It should be:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController,
          didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: OK cool, but if so how would I go about applying the UIImagePicker image to my UIImageView? Thanks for the speedy response!

Answer (score 2):

As everyone suggested, use the didfinishpickingmediawithinfo method and to extract the image in swift 5, iOS 13, use the info dictionary

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
  imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
}
```

Comment: I get this error using this code: Cannot convert value of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey' to expected argument type 'String'